# Cmder - how to add Windows 10 start menu tile?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, cmder

I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 Anniversary Edition on both my desktop and my laptop.

On the former, I can't seem to find a way to add a cmder start menu shortcut. Is it because cmder is just a portable application that comes in a zip package?

The odd thing is that I have that kind of shortcut on my laptop, so I must have found a way back then, but can't remember how I did it. Perhaps it was possible pre-Anniversary and now it's not?

Comment: I just had to right-click on the executable in my folder and then choose "Pin to Start". What a miss!

Answer (score 11):

Although you've solved this yourself, I thought I'd add a step that was preventing me from adding a Cmder shortcut to the start menu. I had forgotten to register it after I'd downloaded it. Per the Cmder [GitHub README](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#shortcut-to-open-cmder-in-a-chosen-folder):

> 1. Open a terminal as an Administrator
> 2. Navigate to the directory you have placed Cmder
> 3. Execute `.\cmder.exe /REGISTER ALL`. If you get a message "Access Denied" ensure you are executing the command in an Administrator prompt.

From there, add it as a shortcut the usual way (Right click > Pin to Start; or make a shortcut and copy it to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`)

As an aside, forgetting this step had made it so the Sublime Text 3 package SendREPL was unable to send snippets to the terminal, which is how I finally managed to figure out what was going on